# Making sense of core taglibs migrating to Websphere 7

Tags: jstl

I am migrating an ADF application to run in Websphere 7.

Basically I am moving to jstl 1.2

I have created a new project and I am now at the point where I can run jsps.

I started getting errors with the taglibs. Then I found out that I have to replace all my c taglib declarations with the new uri of java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core instead of java.sun.com/jstl/core

I did this to every one of my jsp files. Now when I publish and attempt to run it I get this error.

```
[Servlet Error]-[/index.jsp]: com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: /index.jsp(742,56) /included.jsp(4,58) JSPG0240E: Attempt to redefine the prefix "c" to "http://java.sun.com/jstl/core", when it was already defined as "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" in the current scope.
```

Now each page has the new uri. Why would it try to redefine it to the old uri?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the new stuff is very specific in regards to syntax

Notice this if you don't have spaces between the "@" and the "taglib" part of the text it blows up!

Also you have to have the space between the "c" and the end of the tag "%>"

If you don't do this it causes big ol stupid errors that say nothing about how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem at WAS v8. and fix it by:

Admin Console -> Application servers -> (serverName) -> Web
container -> Custom properties :

com.ibm.wsspi.jsp.allowtaglibprefixredefinition=true

[PM38186: JSPG0240E: ATTEMPT TO REDEFINE THE PREFIX WHEN IT WAS ALREADY DEFINED IN CURRENT SCOPE ERROR IN WEBSPHERE APPLICATION SERVER 7](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PM38186)

Answer (score 0):

---

This fixed my problem!! My taglib imports were all the same so I still dont know the root cause of the problem in my environment (WebSphere 7 running in RAD 8.0.3).  It shouldn't complain if the imports all point to the same namespace.  This fix basically tells the server to ignore the error rather than preventing the error occurring.

I'll post back if I find more info.